# What happens to the stdout and stdin for a forked process?

Tags: python, subprocess, fork

I understand the fork function.I know that it duplicates the parent process and after the fork function has been called the parent complete its execution and the child start its execution.
Here is a python code the fork a child process

```
import os
pid, master_fd =os.forkpty()
if pid == 0:
    print ('child')
else:
   print ('parent')
```

Why is the word child doesn’t get printed??

Comment: Why use `os.forkpty()` then instead of `os.fork()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "child" doesn't appear because [`os.forkpty()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.forkpty) creates a new pseudo-terminal and routes the child's output to it.

Your understanding would be correct if you had used [`os.fork()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.fork) instead.

Comment: to see `'child'` string, you could read from `master_fd` in the parent: `print(os.read(master_fd, 512).decode())`